# Golang net/http managed pool Vs implementing a sql style connection pool

Tags: http, go, https, connection, connection-pooling

I have seen some people implement a sql package style connection pools in golang egs([reference1](https://betterprogramming.pub/build-a-tcp-connection-pool-from-scratch-with-go-d7747023fe14)) instead of just using the net/http managed pool. What benefits do we get out of doing this?

One thing I see is the flexibility to distribute the requests across the pool the way you like. Appreciate some light on the topic

Comment: The net/http package does not export an API to the pool.

Comment: @CeriseLimón agree! but how does control over the pool benefit much. If you could mention a few that would be really helpful.

Comment: Database clients are a common example of where TCP connection pooling is useful.  The pool in the net/http package pool is not useful to these clients because the net/http package does not provide a pool API.